# Using Cgroups with Systemd to restrict bash cpu & memory

Tags: centos, systemd, cgroups

I want to restrict every user on my Centos 7 server who is logged in via SSH. They should not be able to use, for example, a forkbomb and kill the whole system. The superuser will have no restriction.

Restricting a service like httpd is no problem with systemd :

```
systemctl set-property httpd.service CPUShares=500 MemoryLimit=500M
```

But how could I get this for each SSH user login session?

I could try to open a new service with:

```
systemd-run --unit=bashtest --slice=btest bash
```

then restrict it with `set-property`.

But I don't know how a user could then log in into this bash session.

Comment: ok a solution is using ulimit in /etc/security/limits.conf, but how could i reach this with cgroups?